# How to replace multiple words from column of type array in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, replace, pyspark

I have seen similar post and tried to implement solution in pyspark however getting errors in some case and in some cases not getting expected output.

Below is my dataframe schema

[image: Dataframe Schema]

and below is sample output.

[image: sample output]

Here, I'm trying to replace following words:

[image: replace word list]

I have around 100+ word list that I'm trying to replace from all rows of this column.

Can you please guide, thank you.

Comment: What error do you see with solutions you mention in first paragraph?

Comment: thanks for comments, I'll re-produce the error and share details with you shortly.